# bluetoothd still installed despite uninstalling bluez

Tags: bluetooth

I have tried to uninstall the `bluez` package, as shown below, but `bluetoothd -v` still outputs a version. Why is this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get autoremove bluez
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'bluez' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothd -v 
5.33
```

Comment: Could you try running `dpkg -l | grep bluez` and [edit] your post to add the output (if there is any)?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is something broken with your installation. Maybe you can repair it by installing *bluez* (again?) and deinstall it in the hope it will then also deinstall *bluetoothd* which is part of the package.

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install bluez
rpi ~$ sudo apt --autoremove purge bluez
```